# Why _init or _create not fired in own jQuery Widget?

Tags: jquery, widget

i try to develop my first jQUery widget:

```
        (function( $ ) {
            $.widget( "ui.weekCalendar", {

                options: { 
                    start : new Date(),
                    end : new Date(),
                },

                // Set up the widget
                _create: function() {
                    alert('GNAAA');
                },

                _setOption: function( key, value ) {
                    switch( key ) {
                        case "clear":
                        break;
                    }

                    $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply( this, arguments );
                    this._super( "_setOption", key, value );
                },


                destroy: function() {
                    $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );

                }
            });
        }( jQuery ) );      

        $('#calendar').weekCalendar();
```

I followed the instructions on http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory . But i dont understand why the _create function did not fired. Even so the _init function get not fired. Whats thet problem here?

Answer (score 0):

What a silly mistake:

```
$('#calendar').weekCalendar();
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#calendar').weekCalendar();          
});
```

cost 3 hours of my life :(